# Discord.py VSCode error when running my code: NameError: name 'TOKEN' is not defined

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so i was trying to run my discord bot and it said NameError: name 'TOKEN' is not defined

```
import discord



client = discord.Client()



client.run (TOKEN)

TOKEN = "token"
```

this is my code tell me what is wrong

Comment: You need to define your token *before* you call it. Also, hide your token and don't share it with anyone :)

Comment: bro i reset my token before i posted it and tysm

Answer (score 2):

Try defining the token before you use it.

```
import discord

    client = discord.Client()
    TOKEN = "Insert Token Here"
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined your token after you referenced it. Put the token definition before `client.run(token)`.

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

TOKEN = 'token'

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Even though you reset your token, we request that you obfuscate it anyway. It is for security and readability.